# Customizing GET Response Using Python Requests Module

Tags: python, oauth, get, python-requests

I'm a newbie to Python here, so bear with me...
Trying to experiment making a simple oAuth call to Instagram API. After you register your application, you get your client ID, client secret, etc, the first step in the oAuth process is to direct the user to this authorization URL:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
```

When I load this URL in a browser with my client ID and Redirect URL, the following URL appears in the browser (for example):

```
http://instagrram.geometryfletch.com/home.html?code=956237827314ee22092384984938
```

My question is, how can I replicate what happens in the browser using the Requests module?

when I try the following:

```
 >>> import requests
 >>> b = requests.get('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=c918883453360349850498&redirect_uri=http://instagrram.myredirect.com/home.html&response_type=code')
 >>> b.text
```

What I get back is this "garbbled" response (I know it's not really grabbled, Requests is doing what I tell it and returning something appropriate):

```
u'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 not-logged-in "> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 not-logged-in "> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie9 not-logged-in "> <![endif]-->\n<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in "> <!--<![endif]-->\n
<head>\n
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    \n
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    \n\n <title>Log in &mdash; Instagram</title>\n\n
    <script type="text/javascript">\
    n
    WebFontConfig = {
    \
    n
    custom: {\n
        families: [\'proxima-nova:n4,n7\'],\n      urls: [\'//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/660508e/cache/styles/fonts.css\']\n    }\n  };\n</script>
    \n
    <script src="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/660508e/scripts/webfont.js" type="text/javascript"
            async></script>
    \n\n \n \n
    <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex">
    \n \n
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    \n
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    \n\n\n \n
    <meta id="viewport" name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    \n\n\n
    <script type="text/javascript">\
    n(function () {\n
        var docElement = document.documentElement;\n
        var classRE = new RegExp(\'(^|\\\\s)no-js(\\\\s|$)\');\n            var className = docElement.className;\n            docElement.className = className.replace(classRE, \'$1js$2\');\n        })();\n        </script>
    \n\n \n\n \n \n \n
    <link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon"
          href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/660508e/images/ico/favicon.ico">
    \n \n \n
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
          href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/660508e/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
    \n
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72"
          href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/660508e/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
    \n
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114"
          href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/660508e/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
    \n
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144"
          href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/660508e/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
    \n \n \n
    <link href="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/660508e/cache/styles/distillery/dialog-main.css"
          type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    \n
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>\n    <style>\n        .dialog-outer {\n            min-height: 0;\n        }\n    </style>\n    
    <![endif]-->\n\n \n
    <script src="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/660508e/scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    \n
    <script src="//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/660508e/scripts/bluebar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    \n
    <script type="text/javascript">\
    n
    $(document).ready(function () {\n
        $("#id_username").focus();\n
        setTimeout(function () {\n
            document.getElementById(\'viewport\').setAttribute(\'content\', \'width=\'+ window.innerWidth + \', user-scalable=no\');\n        }, 5);\n    });\n</script>
    \n\n\n
</head>
\n
<body class="p-dialog oauth-login">\n \n \n
<div class="root">\n \n
    <section class="dialog-outer">\n
        <div class="dialog">\n
            <header>\n <h1 class="logo">Instagram</h1>\n \n</header>
            \n
            <div class="dialog-main">\n \n\n\n\n\n\n\n
                <form method="POST" id="login-form" class="adjacent"
                      action="/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&amp;next=/oauth/authorize/?client_id=c91888345336494ab7ea7046427ca23e%26redirect_uri=http://instagrram.geometryfletch.com/home.html%26response_type=code">
                    \n <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" ..........
```

but how can I get Requests to return just simply the `code:code=956237827314ee22092384984938` as when you load the URL into a browser?

Comment: Is any of the credentials/user information you provided in this question better left secret?

Comment: Why are you doing this, rather than using the perfectly fine [Instagram Python library](https://github.com/instagram/python-instagram)?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke None of that info in the question is my actual credential info, I just made up those creds for posting this question.

Comment: try using request with the cookie from your browser

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because the Instagram Python Library is full of errors and is badly in need of updating, for example: https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/issues/148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For production purposes, you should not re-implement oauth. Please have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauthlib which is an established library for performing the oauth authentication logic. If you want to stick with `requests`, then there also is https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib. Other than that, regarding your question

> My question is, how can I replicate what happens in the browser using
>   the Requests module?

This is not trivial. First, use `curl` or a browser plugin for debugging/reconstructing the protocol flow. The second step then is to rebuild the same flow using `requests`.

Example: When accessing the first URL you mentioned in your question via GET,  the server responds with a [`302 redirection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) whose target is given in the `Location` field of the response *header*. The response also sets a cookie via the `Set-Cookie` header field. All of this is important.

Comment: Thank you for your informative response, much appreciated. Just to be clear, there's not an equivalent of loading that URL in a browser in Requests? I can only really do that with cURL?

Comment: A browser works on a higher level than requests does. You cannot tell requests "please behave like Firefox". However, requests surely provides all the tools you would need to implement a browser yourself. You just have to appreciate that what a browser is doing in the background usually is much more complex than just firing of an HTTP GET request and "displaying" the response. The response is evaluated by all means, and action is taken depending on the specifics of the response, including all header fields.

Comment: You should install a browser plugin that visualizes the HTTP protocol flow. Then access a simple website and carefully look at what happened. Then log in to Facebook and see what happened. It will be quite complex. As I said, all this *can* be re-implemented using requests (or any other HTTP library), but it can be a lot of work.

Comment: Something like this would do the trick? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo?hl=en

Comment: Yeah, right, it looks useful :) In case of Firefox I was using HttpFox or something with "tamper" in its name, but browser plugins emerge and die quickly these days...